# How can I make my middleware respond with a json object if I use an API route

Tags: laravel, middleware

I'm building my first API with Laravel and I'm using JWT for authentication. I don't really understand guards all that well yet but I think I managed to guard my User class. So when I try to reach a route in  my UserController it get's guarded and the Authenticate middleware gets called if the user is no authenticated. The problem is that when I try to use the API route via Postman that I get the following error

ErrorException: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in file

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
         if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 403);
         }
    }
}
```

**api.php**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@index');
```

Comment: Why don't you directly return view, why you want to redirect to route?

Comment: Since this this is an API without any front-end. So I want anyone that tries to interact with the API without a JWT token in the header to get the message that they are not authenticated. I guarded all my controllers with the Auth::guard() and that works great except for the redirect that by default goes to the login web route. So my question is how can I respond with unauthenticated.

Comment: Then maybe you could use: abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');. Read more about that here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors

Comment: This still returns a html page. How do I get it to return a json with unauthorized as message? You must understand nobody will look at this trough the browser.

Comment: Use this: return response()->json(['message' => $message], 403);

Comment: $message should be string 'Unauthorized';

Comment: Return response directly from middleware do not redirect to route.

Comment: I returned it directly from the middleware I'll update the code above. But it throws the following error ErrorException: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206069/discussion-between-n-djokic-and-michael).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use:

```
abort(response()->json('Unauthorized', 403));
```

Comment: Is this better than use a try catch on api requests?

I didnt know you can send a json response on abort, seems a lot easier than try.. catch.. send json

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
// Put your authenticated routes here
});
```

Comment: I assign the middleware in the constructor of my controller instead of making route groups

Comment: Change your  ```return route('unauthorized');``` to  ```return route('login');```

Comment: Why would that matter? I want it to go to a custom api route

Comment: paste the code of web.php where you mentioned the unauthorized

Comment: I have an empty web.php since I don't use web route because this is an API. I posted my api.php

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me for json response if header not passed.

```
protected function redirectTo(Request $request): ?string
{
    if($request->is('api/*')) {
        $ErrorResponse = [
            'success' => false,
            'message' =>'Invalid Token',
        ];
        abort(response()->json($ErrorResponse, 403));
    }

    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    } 
}
```